# Notebooks in Vertex AI

Tags: google-cloud-vertex-ai, gcp-ai-platform-notebook

I was learning about vertex AI notebook creation. I found the below screenshot which shows a number of options.

[image]

However, I only see Python 3, PyTorch 1.12, and TensorFlow Enterprise as options in my GCP environment. Why can't I see the alternative choices?

Answer (score 1):

Few weeks ago the base Vertex AI notebooks image was updated to Debian 11 + Python 3.10. Thus the only available configurations by now are Python 3.10, TensorFlow Enterprise (2.11) and PyTorch 1.13.

If you want to use one of the previous images (ie. Smart Analytics Frameworks, R, Jax experimental, etc), you must:

- hit the "new notebook" button
- click on "customize"
- add your instance details, click on "continue"
- on "environment", select "Debian 10" on operation system and then all the environments on your screenshot will appear.

[image: creating a vertex ai workbench instance]